# read only required data in play 2

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I'm running into the situation where I have numerous pieces of data that are required in my data model but that are provided server side and only displayed in the gui. I haven't found a nice way of doing this yet in play 2 using slick.  Take for example tracking creation and modification of data (created, lastUpdated):

```
    case class TrackedData(id:Option[Long],description:String, created:DateTime:new DateTime(),lastUpdated:DateTime=new DateTime())

    object TrackedDatas extends Table[TrackedData]("TrackedData"){
      def id = column[Long]("id",O.primaryKey)
      def description = column[String]("description", O.NotNull)
      def created = column[Timestamp]("created", O.NotNull)
      def lastUpdated = column[Timestamp]("lastUpdated", O.NotNull)
      def * = id.? ~ created ~ lastUpdated <>(TrackedData.apply _, TrackedData.unapply _)
}
```

In this example "description" is the only thing I want the user to provide, the created and lastUpdated will be provided server side, however i do want to display this information on the web.  To do this seems quite clunky.  First you have to map create and lastUpdated to optional fields so that the form binding won't break when you don't submit them, however this means that you can't use the default case class .apply and .unapply moethods and have to provide the mapping to get around this
The controller then becomes:

```
object TrackedDataController extends Controller {
val form = Form(
    mapping(
      "id" -> optional(longNumber),
      "created" -> optional(jodaDate("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", DateTimeZone.UTC)),
      "lastUpdated" -> optional(jodaDate("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", DateTimeZone.UTC)),
      "description" -> text
    )((id, _, _) => TrackedData(id = id))
      ((trackedData:TrackedData) => Some(trackedData.id,Option(trackedData.created),Option(trackedData.lastUpdated)  ,trackedData.descscription))
  )
}
```

It wouldn't be too bad if this was the exception, however most of the data will follow this pattern (plus createdBy and lastModifiedBy) all of which are required and provided server side but need to be displayed browser side.  Is posting the "readonly" data in hidden fields the only way around this?  The above has the additional problem that you will write over any readonly data unless you explicitely protect it during update by retrieving the existing value and copying it to the incoming data:

```
  update(data:TrackedData){
        val existing:T = this.byId(toSave.id.get).get
        toSave.created = existing.created
        toSave.lastUpdated = new DateTime()
        this.where(_.id===toSave.id).update(toSave)
    }
```

None of this is too terrible, it just seems like there must be a better way.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [play-autosource](https://github.com/mandubian/play-autosource) which basically offers CRUD with different backends (mongo, slick, ...) and does so by operating on Play's json api. Using transformers you can transform and validate your data. However, it's an experimental project.

As a side node, we're working on an open source project which tries to tackle these issues. We'll announce it in mid-march in play mailing group if you're interested.